# wget cookies.txt problem

Tags: wget

I use wget like this:

```
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt downloadlink
```

The download is successful. But the problem is that it stores useless files from the link to the directory after I delete it for many times. It auto creates `www.mylink.com` dir in the directory no matter how many times I delete it. I try to find where the cookies is saved on my server so I can delete them, but I can't find them.

I hope someone can help as the files that are automatically stored are getting bigger each second. Also there's a file called `.fuse_hidden0345bd8d000004e3` which is getting bigger too, and I can't delete it either.

Comment: OP seems to have solved the problem [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12467604&postcount=5). Quoting the "solution": "problem solved,i kill the wget process.thanks guys".

Answer (score 1):

The OP solved the problem and posted the solution [here on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12467604#post12467604).
(Thanks to [vasa1](https://askubuntu.com/users/25656/vasa1) for [finding this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246015/wget-cookies-txt-problem/246095#comment305750_246015).)

<sup>While the problem remains somewhat vague, the solution can be applied easily, so this may help others in the same situation.</sup>

The solution was to kill `wget` (probably with `killall wget` assuming no other important `wget` instances). Apparently the problem related to a session or sessions that had remained open due to running `wget` instances.

More information does not appear to be available.

<sup>**@lance: Please still [post an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) if you can give more information, for example, if you know why your solution worked.**</sup>